# what method performs the same functions as isChecked does in android

Tags: java, android

Hello guys am new and still finding my feet in android programming, now i am developing a quiz application in android, before i was using radio buttons as my answer options and below is the code i used which worked

```
private void setAnswer() {
    if (answer1.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 0;
    if (answer2.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 1;
    if (answer3.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 2;
    if (answer4.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 3;

    Log.d("",Arrays.toString(selected));
    Log.d("",Arrays.toString(correctAns));

}
```

but then i decided use buttons instead of radio buttons, now i want to know which method to use inplace of the "isChecked" since it does not work for buttons. is there a way or another method that will help me achieve what "ischecked" does?

Thanks

Comment: Buttons usually react on being clicked by executing code rather than storing the state in the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean activated = pref.getBoolean("activated", false);
    if(activated == false) {  // User hasn't actived the promocode -> activate it 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("activated", true);
        editor.commit();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set oncheacked change listner on radio button.

```
        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
                //do your logic

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use the buttons, so what should you do is when the user clicks a button, you recognize the click and change the color of the button pressed, resets the other buttons (returning them to the original color) and updates this answer selected.

for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private View mBtn1;
private View mBtn2;
private View mBtn3;
private View mBtn4;
private TextView mTxt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    mBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mBtn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mBtn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    mTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(mBtnClickListener);
    mBtn2.setOnClickListener(mBtnClickListener);
    mBtn3.setOnClickListener(mBtnClickListener);
    mBtn4.setOnClickListener(mBtnClickListener);


}

View.OnClickListener mBtnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    /**
     * This is all sync because we want to have only one event at a time
     * @param v
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                mTxt.setText("button1");
                mBtn1.setBackgroundColor(Colors.RED);
                mBtn2.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn3.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn4.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                mTxt.setText("button2");
                mBtn1.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn2.setBackgroundColor(Colors.RED);
                mBtn3.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn4.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                mTxt.setText("button3");
                mBtn1.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn2.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn3.setBackgroundColor(Colors.RED);
                mBtn4.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                mTxt.setText("button4");
                mBtn1.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn2.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn3.setBackgroundColor(Colors.WHITE);
                mBtn4.setBackgroundColor(Colors.RED);
                break;

        }
    }
} ;
```

}